# I have issues with onEdit() functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm a beginner in Google sheet app script as I'm needing it for the first time now in my internship. I have looked for answers to my questions on many other topics but i have not find the holy answer I'm looking for.

Basically what i want to do is that i have a spreadsheet to manage the stocks and orders of the company I'm working in. So I'm slowly trying to improve it and I want to use several function that are supposed to be triggered with an `onEdit()`. My issue is that, individually I've tried the functions and they are working, but when i put them in the same `onEdit()` function there is one that doesn't work

```
function addRow(lRow) {
  if ( lRow != null ) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(); 
    var range = sh.getRange(lRow,1, 1, lCol);
    sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
    range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {formatOnly:true});
  }  
}
function lastValue(column) {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("K1:K"+lastRow).getValues();

  for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
  return lastRow;
}
function onEdit(){
  myOnEdit()
}
function myOnEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Commandes V3" ) { //checks that we're on Commandes V3 or not
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 23 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column W
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      } 
    }
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = sheet.getRange("J1:J")
  for(i = 2 ; i <= 500 ; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange("J"+ i).getValue() == true ) {
      var derLigne = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("AR54").getValue()
      var l = derLigne-1
      var ai = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A" + i).getValue()
      var bi = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B" + i).getValue()
      var ci = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C" + i).getValue()
      var di = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D" + i).getValue()
      var ei = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + i).getValue()
      var fi = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F" + i).getValue()
      var gi = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G" + i).getValue()
      addRow(l)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A" + derLigne).setValue(ai)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B" + derLigne).setValue(bi)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("K" + derLigne).setValue(ci)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("L" + derLigne).setValue(di)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("M" + derLigne).setValue(ei)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("N" + derLigne).setValue(fi)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("O" + derLigne).setValue(gi)
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("AR54").setValue(lastValue("K")+1);
```

So, to summarize a little bit, the function `addRow` work with the second part of `myOnEdit(`) which is for transferring some cells from a place to another when a tickbox is checked. `LastValue()` works with the last line of `myOnEdit()`, to fill a cell with the number of the last row of a column. The first part of `myOnEdit()` is for adding in the next cell the date when a cell is checked (without the auto update of `now()` ).

My problem is that the function supposed to fill a cell with a date doesn't work here, but when I use it in another gsheet to test it, it works perfectly. I'm really struggling to know why.

(I'm sorry for the several grammatical mistakes i must have done I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: How does the part that is meant to put the date in a cell not work? Are you getting errors? Incorrect values? Value going in wrong cell?

Comment: When i put something in the cell that is supposed to activate it (in the W column), nothing happen. So i don't what is the problem with the code. Because if i use the same code in an other gsheet (and by replacing the name of the sheet too) it's works well, the date comes out in the cell nearby

Comment: I found on a forum the tips to name a function to trigger with onEdit() rather than just using the line directly in the onEdit(), i don't really know if it is effective. With or without this tips, the function does't activate itself

Comment: Thomas I finally had a chance to look at your code and as far as I can see what you've posted isn't complete. Specifically the code after the myOnEdit function doesn't appear to belong to any function.

Comment: Can you try making a very simple script that only writes some values to the cells you want? Maybe there is some kind of protection on them?

Answer (score 0):

When working with an on edit trigger it's better to use the event object instead of "get active" methods like `getActive()`, `getActiveCell()` but this might require to use a function to provide an emulated event object.

Also it might be more convenient to use `const` instead of `var` to prevent redeclaring variables that should not be redeclared. I mention this because the code assign different objects to `r` which could confuse you and others about the purpose of this variable.

```
function debugOnEdit(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const name = 'Commandes V3';
  const e = {
    source: spreadsheet,
    range: spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name).getRange(1,23)
  }
  onEdit(e);
}

function onEdit(e){
  myOnEdit(e);
}

function myOnEdit(e){
  const s = e.range.getSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  ...
}
```

By the other hand, `onEdit` might not be triggered always i.e. a user does multiple edits before the previous `onEdit` execution finish, it should be as fast as possible, and to achieve this the number of calls to `SpreadsheetApp` methods should be minimized and optimized. I.E.

- instead of using `getMaxRows()` use `getLastRow()`
- instead of using multiple `getValue()` / `setValue()` use `getValues()` / `setValues()`

Related

- [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)